# Works on CVX-Matlab but not on CVXPY

Tags: matlab, python, cvx, cvxpy, geometric-programming

I have the following program running correctly in Matlab.

```
cvx_begin gp
variables b(n,1) dc(n,1) v(n,1) p(n,1)
minimize(sum((1./dc)) + sum((1./b)))
subject to
    (diag(b)*A+diag(dc))*v <= v;
    p'*(diag(b)*A+diag(dc)) <= p';
    v>=zeros(n,1);
    bs*ones(n,1) <= b <= ba*ones(n,1);
    (1-dehigh)*ones(n,1) <= dc <= (1-de)*ones(n,1);
cvx_end
```

where `A`, `dehigh`, `de`, `bs`, and `ba` have all been previously defined.

Now, I need to implement this in Python, and I am trying to use CVXPY.

```
b=cp.Variable(shape = (n,),pos=True)
dc=cp.Variable(shape = (n,),pos=True)
v=cp.Variable(shape = (n,),pos=True)
p=cp.Variable(shape = (n,),pos=True)

objective=cp.Minimize(cp.sum(cp.inv_pos(dc))+cp.sum(cp.inv_pos(b)))
constraints=[cp.diag(b)@A@v+cp.diag(dc)@v-v<=0, 
         p.T@cp.diag(b)@A+p.T@cp.diag(dc)-p.T<=0, 
         v>=0, 
         b>=bs, 
         b<=ba, 
         dc>=(1-dehigh), 
         dc<=(1-de)]
prob=cp.Problem(objective,constraints)
prob.solve(gp=True)
```

were, again, `A`, `dehigh`, `de`, `bs`, and `ba` have been previously defined. However, in this case, it does not work. I get the following error

```
raise DGPError("Problem does not follow DGP rules." + append)

DGPError: Problem does not follow DGP rules.The following constraints are not DGP:
diag_vec(reshape(var2532, (5,), F)) @ [[0.08165575 0.0299181  0.002247   0.0277268  0.        
]
[0.02882425 0.0248519  0.0331365  0.0383574  0.00777085]
[0.002247   0.0367646  0.0001932  0.03324015 0.00627815]
[0.0276453  0.037173   0.03463015 0.078643   0.00359125]
[0.         0.00905125 0.00627695 0.00359315 0.        ]] @ var2534 +diag_vec(reshape(var2533, (5,), F)) @ var2534 + -var2534 <= 0.0 , because the following subexpressions are not: 
|--  [[0.08165575 0.0299181  0.002247   0.0277268  0.        ]
[0.02882425 0.0248519  0.0331365  0.0383574  0.00777085]
[0.002247   0.0367646  0.0001932  0.03324015 0.00627815]
[0.0276453  0.037173   0.03463015 0.078643   0.00359125]
[0.         0.00905125 0.00627695 0.00359315 0.        ]]
|--  -var2534
|--  0.0
var2535 @ diag_vec(reshape(var2532, (5,), F)) @ [[0.08165575 0.0299181  0.002247   0.0277268  0.        ]
[0.02882425 0.0248519  0.0331365  0.0383574  0.00777085]
[0.002247   0.0367646  0.0001932  0.03324015 0.00627815]
[0.0276453  0.037173   0.03463015 0.078643   0.00359125]
 0.         0.00905125 0.00627695 0.00359315 0.        ]] + var2535 @ 
diag_vec(reshape(var2533, (5,), F)) + -var2535 <= 0.0 , because the following subexpressions are not:
|--  [[0.08165575 0.0299181  0.002247   0.0277268  0.        ]
[0.02882425 0.0248519  0.0331365  0.0383574  0.00777085]
[0.002247   0.0367646  0.0001932  0.03324015 0.00627815]
[0.0276453  0.037173   0.03463015 0.078643   0.00359125]
[0.         0.00905125 0.00627695 0.00359315 0.        ]]
|--  -var2535
|--  0.0
```

Could anyone please help me? I cannot find the issue.

Comment: DGP = Disciplined Geometric Programming?

Comment: Please write the geometric program in MathJax.  Also, please provide motivation for this question.

Comment: To the extent that this question appears to be about a possible bug in CVXOPT compared with CVX, it's clearly off-topic.

Comment: Try rewriting the first constraint in a mathematically equivalent but computationally different way. The rules for deducing properties of functions/constraints are limited by those patterns built in.